# on cutting edge technologies / with cutting edge technologies

Tags: prepositions

I was making my resume and wanted to include the line "Looking to work __ cutting-edge technologies" but was confused whether to use with or on in the blank space.

Comment: The preposition could make the whole difference to what you intend to say. It is not about grammar but meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two phases are very different!

Option 1: "Looking to work **WITH** cutting-edge technologies" would normally mean that the employer will have such technologies available in the workplace to assist staff with their jobs.

Option 2: "Looking to work **ON** cutting-edge technologies" would normally mean that you want to be the developer of such technologies.

Example 1:

A surgeon applying for a surgical job is hoping that the hospital will have available leading edge scanners, robotic arms, AI diagnosis tools, etc.

Example 2:

An super-bright engineer straight out of uni is hoping that the employer will give her the opportunities to write AI diagnostic software, develop medical micro-robots, etc.

In the first example, you would use WITH.  In the second example you would use ON.

Comment: +1 for the combination of username and avatar. As well as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to use the technology as a tool = "with"

Are you wanting to develop new technologies and be at the forefront of research = "on"